# Filter legend in linked views with plotly

Tags: r, plot, charts, legend, plotly

I am working on a linked plot (similar to [The SharedData plot pipeline](https://plotly-book.cpsievert.me/linking-views-without-shiny.html) from Carson Sievert in plotly for R. The plot shows a legend for one item I currently hover over. However, right now the legend shows two elements, one for the bar chart and one for the line chart.

- How do I delete the first legend element (the red square for the bar chart) and keep only the legend for the line chart (red line)?

Here is current code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(crosstalk)
library(plotly)

sd <- SharedData$new(txhousing, ~city)

base <- plot_ly(sd, color = I("black")) %>%
        group_by(city) %>%
        layout(showlegend = TRUE)

p1 <- base %>%
      summarise(has = sum(is.na(median))) %>%
      filter(has > 0) %>%
      arrange(has) %>%
      add_bars(x = ~has, y = ~factor(city, levels = city), 
       hoverinfo = "none", showlegend = FALSE) %>%
      layout(
      barmode = "overlay",
        xaxis = list(title = "Number of months missing"),
        yaxis = list(title = "")
      ) 

p2 <- base %>%
   add_lines(x = ~date, y = ~median, alpha = 0.3, showlegend = FALSE) %>%
   layout(xaxis = list(title = ""))

gp <- subplot(p1, p2, titleX = TRUE, widths = c(0.3, 0.7)) %>% 
  layout(margin = list(l = 120)) %>%
  highlight(color = "red",
        defaultValues = "Victoria",
        selected = attrs_selected(showlegend = TRUE, mode = "lines"
    ))

 gp
```

It was mentioned somewhere that the final removal of the legend element may work, but its not working for me here.

```
gp$x$data[[1]]$showlegend <- FALSE
```

Comment: As far as I know you cannot do that directly in Plotly. You could however add Javascript code to your plot to take care of what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If Plotly doesn't provide us a method to hide legends created by `highlight`, then let's use Plotly's own functions to do so.

Javascript code which is needed to hide the trace once:

```
var updated = {showlegend: false};
var myPlot = document.getElementsByClassName('plotly')[0];
Plotly.restyle(myPlot, updated, [2]);
```

*In this case it is always the third element `[2]` which needs its legend hidden, in general it would be preferable to get the index dynamically based on some conditions.*

Let's add this to Plotly's `on_click` event to make sure that the legend will be invisible in the future as well.

```
myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){
  Plotly.restyle(myPlot, updated, [2]);
});
```

And finally add everything to the output and we are good.

```
javascript <- "
var updated = {showlegend: false};
var myPlot = document.getElementsByClassName('plotly')[0];
Plotly.restyle(myPlot, updated, [2]);
myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){
  Plotly.restyle(myPlot, updated, [2]);
});
"

w <- plotly::as_widget(gp)
w <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(w, onStaticRenderComplete(javascript), data=list(''))
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(w, "cities.html")
w
```

[image]