# in R plotly can we show only some levels at first

Tags: r, graph, plotly

In R plotly, when you choose a "color", you have by default a legend on the right, and clicking on a particular level will make every points of that levels disappear from the graph. The legend entries is then greyed, and you can clic again on it to make points reappear. Example :

```
library(plotly)
iris %>%
  plot_ly(x= ~Sepal.Length,y=~Sepal.Width,color = ~Species) %>%
  add_markers()
```

Is it possible that, when the graph is produced, I have only Virginica and setosa plotted, but versicolor is greyed so that if the user wants to see them, he only has to click on it.

My plotly graph is embedded in html in rmarkdown.

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903136/filter-legend-in-linked-views-with-plotly

Comment: Try with `plot_ly(x= ~Sepal.Length,y=~Sepal.Width, color = ~Species, visible = ~ifelse(Species == "versicolor", "legendonly", TRUE))`

Comment: that's great, thank you ! I am not sure about how SO works but why didn't you make an answer ?

Comment: Well @stefan if you would be so kind : your solution works perfectly but I can't reproduce it on another data set. Example on diamonds : diamonds %>%
  sample_n(200) %>%
  plot_ly(x=~price,y=~depth, color = ~cut,
          visible = ~ifelse(cut == "Premium", "legendonly",TRUE)) %>%
  add_markers()

Comment: Try with rearranging before passing your df to plotly, i.e. arrange(cut). There is probably a reason for why it works this way but ... to be honest, this is the kind of thing which drives me crazy when working with plotly. (:

Comment: Thank you it works ! Like you say it's rather crazy...